# テンプレートのカスタマイズについて

Tags: onsen-ui

ons-list-item のテンプレートをカスタマイズしたいと思い、framework/templates 以下を確認したのですが、テンプレートそのものが存在しません。
実態はどこにあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

`<ons-list-item>`にはテンプレートは存在しません。コンパイル時に`.list__item`や`.ons-list-item-inner`といったクラスが付加されるだけです。

カスタマイズしたいということですが、見た目を整えたいだけなら`modifier`属性が使えます。
http://ja.onsen.io/reference/ons-list-item.html#modifiers

凝ったHTML構造にしたいのであれば、そもそも`<ons-list>`を使う必要は無いように思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 modifierだけで対応できないのとアプリ全体で変更したいのでテンプレートがあればそちらで対応したいと考えていました。 自前でなんとかしようと思います。 ありがとうございました。